# Workbook Allow Paste Special Values Only

Tags: vba, custom-ui

I'm in need of some expert help, i have a workbook where i need to only allow Paste Special Values. This particular workbook as special formatting ect. that I don't want overwritten when a user does a standard paste vs. paste values. I tired some VBA but couldn't get that to work quite right, and also tried the custom ui route and was able to disable the entire idMso PasteGalleryMini but i need to keep these paste special values here.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) a couple of ways you could try.

1. Have 2 sheets in your workbook, one is for user-entered data, and the other is for formatted display of data. The formatted display sheet is protected so cannot be amended by the user - it picks up the data from the user-entered sheet which is not protected but formatting is less important. So the user cannot interfere with the formatting or layout of the protected sheet.
   This approach may require quite a bit of code to ensure validation and management of data between the input sheet and the display sheet, for example if you expect the user to insert rows etc., but if your requirement is simple then it's quite acheiveable.
2. Allow the user to paste with formatting but then reset the formatting after the paste has been done. I have found a good approach is to use your own custom styles, where the style can define all aspects of the appearance of the cells. The user can paste data into the sheet, then when finished have a macro trigger to run code that cleans up all the formatting by setting the styles of the different areas of your sheet to the appropriate custom styles. This approach is very effective, specially if you might want to alter the styles later - you may be able just to change the style definition and don't have to change the code. You can make this easier if you have a separate sheet on which all your custom styles are listed with their names and example values in cells which are formatted with that named style. The custom styles sheet can be hidden/protected to avoid users making changes.